# Next - router.replace: how to give it a redirect instruction

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to learn Next.js.

I have a login handler with:

```
import { LOGIN_TOKEN_KEY,REDIRECT_PATH } from "lib/config"

function Login() {
  const client = useApolloClient()
  const [login, { loading }] = useLoginMutation()
  const router = useRouter()
  const redirect = router.query[REDIRECT_PATH] as string | undefined
 

const onSubmit = (data: LoginInput) => {
    return form.handler(() => login({ variables: { data } }), {
      onSuccess: async (data) => {
        await fetch("/api/login", {
          method: "post",
          body: JSON.stringify({ [LOGIN_TOKEN_KEY]: data.login.token }),
        })
        client.writeQuery<MeQuery>({ query: MeDocument, data: { me: data.login.user } })
        router.replace(redirect || "/dashboard")
      },
    })
  }
```

Inside lib/config, REDIRECT_PATH is defined as:

```
export const REDIRECT_PATH = "redirect"
```

What I am trying to achieve, is that on login, the redirect points to a dashboard. Currently, I have a file called pages/dashboard/index.tsx.

In that page, I have:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Text } from "@chakra-ui/react"

import { UserDashboardLayout } from "components/UserDashboardLayout"

export default function DashboardHome() {
  return (
    <Text>test route redirect</Text>
  )
}

DashboardHome.getLayout = (page: React.ReactNode) => <UserDashboardLayout>{page}</UserDashboardLayout>
```

I have a layout that I'm trying to use as follows:

```
import * as React from "react"
import {
  Box,
  Flex,
  Link,
  LinkProps,
  Spinner,
  Stack,
  Text,} from "@chakra-ui/react"
import NextLink from "next/link"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

// import { Role } from "lib/graphql"
import { useLogout } from "lib/hooks/useLogout"
import { useMe } from "lib/hooks/useMe"
import { Nav } from 'components/Nav'

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode
}
export function UserDashboardLayout(props: Props) {
  const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode()
  const isDark = colorMode === "dark"

  const logout = useLogout()
  const { me, loading } = useMe()
  const router = useRouter()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) return
    if (!me ) {
      router.replace(`/`)
    }
  }, [loading, me, router])

  const homeLinkColor = useColorModeValue("black", "white")
  const bg = useColorModeValue("white", "gray.900")
  const borderColor = useColorModeValue("gray.100", "gray.900")
  if (loading || !me ) {
    
    return (
      <Center minH="100vh">
        <Spinner />
      </Center>
    )
  }
  return (
   
    <>
    <Nav  />
    <Flex w="100vw" h="100vh" overflow="hidden">
      <Flex
        flexDir="column"
        justify="space-between"
        w={{ base: "70px", md: "200px" }}
        p={{ base: 4, md: 8 }}
        py={8}
        h="100vh"
        bg={bg}
        borderRight="1px solid"
        borderColor={borderColor}
      >
         
    
        <Stack spacing={4}>
        
          <SidebarLink href="/dashboard" icon={<Box boxSize="18px" as={CgHome} />} color={homeLinkColor}>
            Home
          </SidebarLink>
          <SidebarLink href="/u/testcontentloads" >
            test layout loads
          </SidebarLink>
          
          
        </Stack>
        <Stack>
       
          
          <Button variant="outline" onClick={() => logout()} size="sm">
            <Icon boxSize="20px" as={CgExternal} mr={{ base: 0, md: 2 }} />
            <Text d={{ base: "none", md: "block" }}>Logout</Text>
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </Flex>
      <Box
        w={{ base: "calc(100vw - 70px)", md: "calc(100vw - 200px)" }}
        px={{ base: 4, md: 10 }}
        py={8}
        overflow="scroll"
      >
        {props.children}
      </Box>
    </Flex>
    </>
  )
}

interface SidebarLinkProps extends LinkProps {
  href: string
  icon: React.ReactNode
  children: string
}

function SidebarLink({ href, icon, ...props }: SidebarLinkProps) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const isActive = router.asPath.includes(href)
  return (
    <NextLink passHref href={href}>
      <Link
        display="flex"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent={{ base: "center", md: "flex-start" }}
        fontWeight="300"
        color={isActive ? "teal" : undefined}
        {...props}
      >
        <Center w="26px">{icon}</Center>
        <Text ml={2} d={{ base: "none", md: "block" }}>
          {props.children}
        </Text>
      </Link>
    </NextLink>
  )
}
```

I have 2 pages in my test. The first is saved in a file at pages/admin/users/index.tsx. It says "home page at basic localhost3000 url". The second is saved at pages/dashboard/index.tsx. It says "test route redirect for dashboard url extension".

I expect, the on success handler of the login page to send me to the the dashboard page. it doesn't. It sends me to the first page. I know the route to the dashboard page works, because I can add a link to it from the nav bar when the page has loaded. i just can't figure out how to get the login handler to redirect to it on success.

I can't find what I need to do to get the login redirect to accept the page, wrapped inside the UserDashboardLayout. It is loading a page, and it does use the same text, but it does not load the layout until I give the browser the url extension.

I can't see what I've done wrong with this redirect request in the login success handler - I've made the best sense of [this documentation][1] as I can manage, but I'm lost for what to try next.

When I try to console log the redirect inside the login success handler, I get undefined back.

when I remove the redirect portion of that line, so that the redirect just says:

```
 router.replace("/dashboard")
        // router.replace('/dashboard')
        console.log(redirect, REDIRECT_PATH)
```

the page at localhost3000 loads without the /dashboard extension.

When i console log REDIRECT_PATH, it returns redirect.

When I console log redirect, it returns undefined.

I don't understand how to give next an instruction for how to redirect on successful login and am stuck for ideas to research what's going wrong.
[1]: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreplace

Comment: The login component is used in the navbar. The on success handler points to the dashboard page, after success in the login handler  - except I can't get it to direct to that page from the login handler. I can add a link inside any page and get to the dashboard page, but I can't seem to get the login handler to do that

Comment: Are you passing the `redirect` query parameter when navigating to the login page?

Comment: I don't know what that means? When I log redirect, inside the on success handler on the login page, it returns undefined

Comment: If that's the case then `router.replace("/dashboard")` gets called. Are you sure there's no other redirect happening once you're in the dashboard page? What's the value of `me` in the `UserDashboardLayout`'s `useEffect`? That may be triggering another redirect to the homepage.

Comment: There is a router.replace line in the dasboard layout (as shown in the post), but it only runs if the page is loading or there is no me. Not sure how to log me from the dashboard, when the dashboard wont load from the login handler. Thanks vm for the thoughts on how to investigate. I don't know what to do next to try and figure this out.

Comment: I tried changing the router.replace("/") that is inside the useEffect in the UserLayoutDashboard, to router.replace/("profile") just to see if it was reading that instruction - but it wasn't

Comment: Do you have a public repo or codesandbox where one could reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'll make one now. I am trying to use the https://github.com/NoQuarterTeam/boilerplate repo - all i've done is rename admin to dashboard and try to point the login redirect to the admin page (all users are admins for my attempt)

Comment: You gave me an idea to test last night, which did work to find the problem. I had a test to see if the page was loading that was in a loop. That was messing up the flow. If you want the points, I'm happy to send them to you - you gave me the idea to check for what was in the steps to get to the login page

Comment: I actually haven't solved the problem. I have just created a new one by removing this limb of the problem. currenlty, I can't rely on the redirect on successful login - it will either load a home page or it wont - but now it's not because of the loading error. If I ever figure it out, I'll share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Redirect query parameter**

Let's assume that a user from page `/posts/12` wants to write some comments and he/she goes throw the login form but after authorization, he/she gets to the `dashboard` page. Now the user needs to browse again that post page to write the comment. But what if we redirect the user back to the page where he/she was before the authorization.

For that, we should add redirect params to URL: `/login?redirect=post%2F123`.

If we do not assign the `redirect` query parameter in the URL we get an undefined value:

```js
const redirect = router.query[REDIRECT_PATH] as string | undefined
```

Since the redirect is undefined the redirection will be to the home page `/`:

```js
router.replace(redirect || "/")
```

Try to do something like this in order to get the dashboard:

```js
router.replace(redirect || "/dashboard")
```